# Same file name on iterating ListObject

Tags: go, minio

I want read a list of files within a bucket in the minio storage. Following the documentation i do these following steps:

```
var listFile []*string
minioClient, err := minio.New(location, user, password, true)
// Create a done channel.
doneCh := make(chan struct{})
defer close(doneCh)
// Recursively list all objects in 'mytestbucket'
recursive := true
bucket := "private"
url := "production/font/"
objectCh := minioClient.ListObjects(bucket, url, recursive, doneCh)
for message := range objectCh {
    listFile = append(listFile, &message.Key)
}
return listFile, err
```

When i read the file list i will obtain an array with 24 items but with the same file name, eg.:

```
"production/font/merriweathersans-regular-webfont.ttf",
"production/font/merriweathersans-regular-webfont.ttf",
"production/font/merriweathersans-regular-webfont.ttf",
"production/font/merriweathersans-regular-webfont.ttf",
"production/font/merriweathersans-regular-webfont.ttf",
...
```

But i should see all files name of that directory:

```
"production/font/Nexa-Light.ttf",
"production/font/Nexa-Bold.ttf",
"production/font/merriweathersans-regular-webfont.ttf",
....
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `for range` loops **reuse** their iteration variables, i.e. the `message` variable represents a single storage location and that location doesn't change on the next iteration, only the data in it changes. So in each iteration, when you take the address of that location (`&message.Key`) you always get the same address and therefore the `listFile` slice contains pointers each pointing to that single location. You need to copy the iteration variable and the you can take the address of that. e.g. `message := message` and then `listFile = append(listFile, &message.Key)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a typo in your loop, that is appending `&message.Key` to the `listFile`. Here `message` variable is always the same and you are appending the same variable, so `listFile` always points to the last value of `message.key`.

To fix this, you can:

```
for message := range objectCh {
    tmpMessage := message
    listFile = append(listFile, &tmpMessage.Key)
}
```

Comment: It's a `range` over a channel, not a slice or array, so *no* `idx` there, only value.

Comment: @mkopriva Oh, I didn't notice, thanks. I updated the answer.